# Unable to connect to mongo from CL but successful from Pymongo

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to connect to mongo like this from the same host, ie. `host_addr`

```
mongo  host_addr:27030 -u user -p password
```

And I get the below response :

> MongoDB shell version v3.4.6
>
> connecting to: host_addr:27030
>
> MongoDB server version: 3.4.6
>
> 2017-11-18T17:44:39.055-0800 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: Authentication failed. :
>
> DB.prototype._authOrThrow@src/mongo/shell/db.js:1461:20
>
> @(auth):6:1
>
> @(auth):1:2
>
> exception: login failed

I use the same credentials to connect using Pymongo from my python application and it works.

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify which database you're authenticating against:

```
mongo  host_addr:27030 -u user -p password --authenticationDatabase <yourDBName>
```

**or**

```
mongo  host_addr:27030/<yourDBname> -u user -p password
```

**or**

```
mongo --host host_addr --port 27030 -u user -p password --authenticationDatabase <yourDBName>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that mongo tries to connect to the test database by default and ur user is probably on the admin db.

try:

```
mongo admin host_addr:27030 -u user -p password
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding `--authenticationDatabase admin` worked for me. It depends on where the login users are defined. Mine exist in `System\admin` database.